# Mouses cursor speed UWP C++/CLI

Tags: c++, performance, uwp, managed, mouse-cursor

I am trying to get the mouse cursor speed in a windows UWP app using C++/CLI. In a traditional Win32 App I would use the SystemParametersInfo function, something like:

```
SystemParametersInfo(
     SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 
      0, 
      uint.Parse(args[0]), 
      0);
```

However, I do not have this available in an UWP app. I looked everywhere without any luck.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft want you to [be able to] do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

After having spend a lot of time investigating this, and not having received any answer, I think I will close of this issue, with the conclusion that this cannot be done in an UWP environment using C++/CLI. It is apparently a restriction of an UWP App.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the mouse cursor speed in a windows UWP app using C++/CLI.

The problem is your `uiAction` is not correct. `SPI_SETMOUSESPEED` is used to set mouse speed. please use `SPI_GETMOUSESPEED` to replace.

> Retrieves the [current mouse speed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa). The mouse speed determines how far the pointer will move based on the distance the mouse moves. The pvParam parameter must point to an integer that receives a value which ranges between 1 (slowest) and 20 (fastest). A value of 10 is the default. The value can be set by an end-user using the mouse control panel application or by an application using SPI_SETMOUSESPEED.

```
SPI_GETMOUSESPEED
0x0070

SPI_SETMOUSESPEED
0x0071
```

Comment: Thanks Nico, but I am sorry if I mislead you with using the SystemParametersInfo function wrongly above. The thing is, that even though the parameters are incorrect in the above example it is not so relevant, as I cannot even call this function in an UWP environment using C+/CLI. So, what I need is how this can be done In an UWP environment using C+/CLI and not how it is, correctly, done in the old/Win32 environment. Hope this clarifies it a bit. Thanks anyway

Comment: I have not tested within c++ CLI, I run above code by using pinvoke in c#, it could retrieve default mouse speed 10.